# can't run my node js project on my cpanel

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
Run NPM Install
returncode: 126
stdout:
> zenitcouture@1.0.0 start /home/zenitcou/zenitcouture
> nodemon app.js
stderr:
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /home/zenitcou/nodevenv/zenitcouture/10/bin/node but npm is using /opt/alt/alt-nodejs10/root/usr/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
sh: /home/zenitcou/zenitcouture/node_modules/.bin/nodemon: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! zenitcouture@1.0.0 start: `nodemon app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the zenitcouture@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/zenitcou/.npm/_logs/2021-10-09T17_17_22_982Z-debug.log
```

the above is my code. I'm trying to upload it to my cpanel and run it but i keep getting this error. I've stopped the app, and restarted it, the same error.

```
An error occured during installation of modules. The operation was performed, but check availability of application has failed. Web application responds, but its return code "500 Internal Server Error" or content type before operation "text/html; charset=UTF-8" doesn't equal to contet type after operation "text/html; charset=UTF-8".
```

i also get this error above if i dont stop the app before installing npm

Comment: I guess you'll need to run sudo npm install

Comment: You probably need to reach out to your cpanel host for that.

Comment: @sid how do i run sudo npm install